# Smoothing Uneven Concave Surface

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, knife-tool

After applying the boolean modifier for the cut, I need to clean up the scruffy looking concave section of this object.  There was a method on youtube using the knife tool plus some additional shortkeys to get a really nice smooth surface, but that video no longer exists. How can I achieve that smooth look on this surface?[image]

Comment: Depending on what your topology looks like, it could be as simple as going into the Object Data properties panel, and checking Auto Smooth under Normals.

Comment: @John You can get a certain level of acceptance playing around the Auto Smooth parameters, but it seems that it doesn't work with the sub surf modifier. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to spend time creating the shape in your mesh. Now that I look at it again, it really isn’t the right place to bring in a Bool.

Comment: If I were you I would apply the Bool at this point and then go in for cleanup. If it’s ludicrous than I’d just start over.